# jquery fire event on value change

Tags: jquery, live

Hi all i am look for way to fire and event event time the values changes.

So i have got a live clock running in a div called.

```
<span id="LiveClockIE">The time is: 9:37:24 AM</span>
```

What i want to do is fire a event everytime the clock changes ie every sec??

tried

```
  $("#LiveClockIE").val().change(function () {
             console.log('change event');
            })
            .change();
```

And

```
$("#LiveClockIE").change(function () {
             console.log('change event');
            })
            .change();
```

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change event you have in your code example only fires on some types of fields and only when the field loses focus.  It does not ever fire when the content is changed programmatically.

If you actually wanted to know every time some piece of JS code was updating the LiveClockIE span, then you'd probably have to hook into or modify whatever code was doing the updating of the span and have it call your callback too every time it changes the clock time.

FYI, this will call yourFunc once a second (though not exactly at the same moment that the clock is updated, but just as frequently).

```
setInterval(yourFunc, 1000);
```

Comment: how can i make it fire when the value changes programmatically. Whats best to use???

Comment: There is no DOM support for those kinds of change events.  You would have to modify the clock code to notify you every time it updated the time.

Comment: I don't know.  You'd have to look at the clock code (which you have not included any info about).  It probably sets `innerHTML` on the span.  How about giving yourself a meaningful user name so if we cross paths again, we'd recognize each other?

Comment: ill change the users name cheers. i am just using a clock as an example. i am working on a geo location app but because i am static and not moving around i am using a clock, just to try the change event. What i need is everytime my geoloaction "clock" value changes insert it into a database. thanks

Comment: Go to the source of the actual change and install a callback there rather than try to watch some part of the web page.  Show us the code that is making the change and we can offer more specific advice.